# Assembling armv8-a neon with gnu assembler

Tags: arm, gnu-assembler, neon

I am trying to assemble aarch64 neon instructions with the gnu assembler. The example is from the [neon programming quick reference](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/operating-systems-blog/posts/arm-neon-programming-quick-reference)

```
    .text

    .align 4

    .global add_float_neon2

    .type add_float_neon2, %function

add_float_neon2:

.L_loop:

    ld1     {v0.4s}, [x1], #16

    ld1     {v1.4s}, [x2], #16

    fadd    v0.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s

    subs x3, x3, #4

    st1  {v0.4s}, [x0], #16

    bgt .L_loop

    ret
```

When running the gnu assembler I get the following error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as -march=armv8-a -mfpu=neon test.s

test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:13: Error: bad instruction `ld1 {v0.4s},[x1],#16'
test.s:15: Error: bad instruction `ld1 {v1.4s},[x2],#16'
test.s:17: Error: bad instruction `fadd v0.4s,v0.4s,v1.4s'
test.s:19: Error: ARM register expected -- `subs x3,x3,#4'
test.s:21: Error: bad instruction `st1 {v0.4s},[x0],#16'
test.s:25: Error: bad instruction `ret'
```

It cannot assemble any instructions with the `<Vd>.<T>` operand formats, even if I try running it with a single instruction. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems you are using the wrong toolchain(`armv7`). Get the `aarch64` version instead.

Comment: Thanks! Installing `binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu` did the job!